# Change path to database in Microsoft Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, filepath

I need to make something in the database. It was saved as .accdb files. I copied this from my workplace and now I want to edit it on my home computer, but when I've open these files and tried to see already made commands I got an error message that I have not a valid path. This error occurs while I want to open command forms for adding and deleting, which need to use other databases.
How can I change the path so my Access will know, where these files are stored on my computer?

Comment: Your question is missing vital information, such as if there are linked tables in the database, if it contains VBA, when exactly the error occurs (on opening the file, when opening a specific form or table?). Please read in on [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you for pointing this. I added an information about situation when this error occurs.

Comment: That doesn't make it MCVE. Please add information on the presence of linked tables, the location of those tables, and any VBA included in the form that causes the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to band option *(Database) Tools*.

Select *Linked Table Mana*ger (label is localized).

Mark the checkbox down-left: *Always as for new location*.

Click *Mark All*, then *OK*.

Input the folder name where the data file exists.