# Issues with Access Database 2000 using Access 2016

Tags: database, ms-access, updates

First of all, I'm really a begginer to Access. I have basic knowledge about databases ( running on SQL mostly ), so thanks for dumbing down the answers a bit.

The company I work for created a database using Access 2000 and built on it since then. They wish to use the newest version of Access instead of the 2003 one but want to keep the database as it is.

When the database ( .mdb file ) is opened with Access 2003, it opens on the Form called "Fiche Principale", and immediately gives the first entry of the database and all of its related informations. This is what the company wants to keep.

However, when opened with the new Access, it prompts a dialog box :

```
Enter Value Parameter :
Form!Fiche Recherche Contact!REFINTERNE
```

( REFINTERNE is an Id )

I looked it up online, there's a lot of issues related to the Enter Value Parameter dialog box, mostly people forgot ' " ' when using a string, or just some misspeling with parameter names. I checked that as best as I could, but it might still be an error like this.

Weird thing is, the database and forms are working fine on the old Access, so I tried converting the databse to a .accdb file but the problem remains.

I hope I'm clear enough, don't hesitate to ask question to clarify if needs be.

Thanks alot

EDIT : I found this code related to "Fiche Recherche Contact" :

```
Function rech2()
Forms![Fiche Principale].RecordSource = "Fiche Principale - Filtre Contacts"
'Forms![Fiche Recherche Contacts].RecordSource = ""
End Function
```

From what i can understand, "Fiche Recherche Contact" is a sub-form of "Fiche Principale".

EDIT : I know giving a precise answer will be difficult, so I'm more looking for a general direction in order to know where to look.

Comment: That would indicate that the form "Fiche Recherche Contact" isn't open but should be. Later versions of access might need the location of the database set as a trusted location to enable macro's / vba to run correctly.

Comment: When I open the form "Fiche Recherche Contact", nothing show up in Form Mode but it exist in Creation Mode. 
I tried reseting the location of the database folling [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45432794/change-path-to-database-in-microsoft-access-2013) but the issue remains.

Comment: It sounds as if the form is being hidden when it's open or is "off screen". Maybe some values are held on this form when other functions are running. Without seeing all the code associated with the database opening this is difficult to debug.

Comment: Being new to access, I'm not even sure where to find the code. I edited this post  with some of it, hopefully it's the good one.

Comment: If you haven't altered it that line is commented out ?

Comment: This line was already commented out. It doesn't change anything when I remove the apostrophe, neither in Access 2003 or 365.